# How to deploy a Laravel + Vue project with Heroku

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, heroku

I have deployed a Laravel project on Heroku that uses Vue components, but the content of these components doesn't appear on the app's webpages. Only contents of .blade.php files are being rendered.

So, how do I deploy a Laravel and Vue project properly with Heroku?

My app's Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

I tried adding some extra commands to the dyno such as `web: npm run watch & vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` and `web: npm install vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` but I had no luck.

And no, my app runs perfectly fine localy with `npm run watch` and `php artisan serve` commands, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it is needed to enable node.js:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

Set:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Then add postinstall in package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run prod"
  }
```

You can also clear cache on laravel application deployed to heroku.

After you do theses steps, it will be possible to run node commands.

Here is reference what I used: https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/using-laravel-and-laravel-elixir-on-heroku

Comment: could you please help me i've been stucked with similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084954/laravel-vuejs-app-does-not-update-after-deploying-to-heroku